# Can you increase the salary for 2 different job ID's in the same select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have to list the employee ID, full name, job ID, and modify the salary for employees whose monthly earning (without the increase) is outside the range $6,000 – $11,000. They have to be employed as Vice Presidents or Managers.

VP’s need a 30% salary increase and Managers need a 20% salary increase.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT 'Emp# ' || employee_id AS "Emp#", 
       first_name || ' ' || last_name
       || ' is ' || Job_id || ' and will get a new salary of '
       || (salary + (salary*0.20))
 FROM employees
WHERE (job_id LIKE '%VP%' OR job_id LIKE '%MAN%')
  AND (salary > 11000 OR salary < 6000);
```

Right now I'm giving a 20% increase to both VP's and Managers, but I need to give 30% to VP's and 20% to Managers.

Is it possible for me to do both of these salary raises in a single select statement, or do I have to do them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a case statement like below

```
case when job_id like '%VP%' then 1.3 else 1.2 end * salary
```